# Swift Can't delegate

Tags: swift, delegates

I have 2 vcs and need send data from one to another

First VC (send Data):

```
protocol CSPFamilyFeedVCDelegate : class{
func getImage(image: String)
}
class CSPFamilyFeedVC: UITableViewController {
....
weak var delegate: CSPFamilyFeedVCDelegate?
....
func presentPhoto(sender: AnyObject){
    let index = sender.tag - feedModelFunctions.tagForElements
    self.delegate?.getImage(feedModelFunctions.fullPost[index].images)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("CSPPresentPhoto", sender: self)
   }
}
```

Second VC (get Data):

```
class CSPPhotoBrowserViewVC: UIViewController, CSPFamilyFeedVCDelegate{
...
    func getImage(image: String) {
     print(1)
    }
...}
```

Segue from First to second
Can't get data at second vc

Comment: Are you sure you are properly setting your delegate?

Comment: Are you displaying both of your viewcontrollers at the same time ?

Comment: If you want to use Segue, you need to implement `prepareForSegue()`. Get your `segue.destinationController` to set you data.